# DART: implementation of abstract method in extended class

Tags: dart, private, abstract

I have two class in file myclass.dart:

```
abstract class A{
  _myAbstractMethod();
}

class B extends A{

}
```

At this point the compilation says: MISSING CONCRETE IMPLEMENTATION OF ***One._Method***.
This is the correct behavior!

The problem came when I put each class on separated files. When I move class B declaration to another file, the compilation do not tell anymore the missing implementation.

Pay attention that the method on class A is private, and the "problem" only occurs with each class in separated files.

Comment: @Nagual, i Try to use "@visibleForOverriding ". The result was: The member '_myAbstractMethod' is annotated with 'visibleForOverriding', but this annotation is only meaningful on declarations of public members.
Why my example WORK for class on same file and DONT WORK for class on diferent files?

Comment: As I alluded to in the comments to the linked question, abstract private methods don't make much sense, and it's a bad design if you want the abstract class to be extended outside of the library.  Private symbols in Dart are private to the *library*, so if you want a method to have any visibility outside of the library, it must not be private, and *then* you can use things like `@visibleForOverriding` to try to restrict access. If you don't control the base class, then you're out of luck.  There are various ways that a Dart class can prevent itself from being extended, and this is one of them.

Comment: @jamesdlin, I believe that I don't have the mental knowledge to understand why one good feature work if two structures are on same file and don't work if they are in separated files. Can you send me a link or any direction to understand this phenomenon?
I really don't get why DART only do not let me do this on separated files.

Comment: As I mentioned, private members are private to the *library*, not to the class.   A Dart "library" usually means the `.dart` file.

Comment: I think I can get around this passing a method to the constructor, and call the method with the customized behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior because the method on the class `A` is library private.

That means that when put in a second library, the class `B` doesn't *know* that `A` has a method named `_myAbstractMethod`, and if it did, it couldn't even write the name (writing `_myAbstractMethod` in the library of `B` represents a different name, private to the second library).

So, from `B`'s perspective it correctly implements `A`'s (empty) interface.
All is well.

The `A` class disagrees, but there is nothing it can do.
To make the `B` class complete, the compiler adds a synthetic `_myAbstractMethod` (using `A`'s name) implementation which throws when called.

This is expected behavior.